# ASP.NET MVC 2 - How to ignore an entire directory using IgnoreRoute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I've tried the following two methods to try and ignore my "Assets" folder, but I keep coming up with errors.  Can anyone tell me exactly how the Ignore Regex is supposed to look?

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("/Assets/")
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*assets}", New With {.assets = "\/Assets\/(.*)"})
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = false
routes.IgnoreRoute("Assets/{*pathInfo}")
```

Comment: There is the no need to explicitly set RouteExistingFiles to false as this is the default.

Comment: I would like to know how to ignore existing files in a certain directory but still route all other existing files everywhere.

Answer (score -2):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Ignore/");
```

will prevent the standard

> The controller for path '/Crap/Home' was not found or does not implement IController.
>   Asp.net mvc exception.